# Finding array data in worksheet values - Is not picking up the certain values

Tags: vba, excel

I've been changing the numbers around in the "offset" to try to move the names and numbers to where I want them in my other sheet, but, the phone numbers for David and Andrea won't transfer over.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, bFound As Boolean, rFound As Range
Dim a As Long, aNames As Variant

aNames = Array("David", "Andrea", "Caroline")

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E30").Cells
                For a = LBound(aNames) To UBound(aNames)
                    Set rFound = .Find(What:=aNames(a), MatchCase:=False,   LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchFormat:=False)
                    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                        bFound = True
                        Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(3) = rFound.Value
                        Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(3, 1) = rFound.Offset(, 1).Value
                    End If
                Next a
            End With
    End


If Not bFound Then
    MsgBox "None of the sheets contains the names " & Chr(10) & _
        "'" & Join(aNames, "', '") & "' in cells A1:E30.", vbInformation, "Not Found"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried:
Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 5) = rFound.Value

instead of:
Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(3) = rFound.Value

and: 
rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End If

Comment: that still only picks up Caroline's phone number

Comment: yeah not sure what I was thinking there. that's gonna return all the count of rows on the worksheet.  1048576 - 

you are only looking inside of the range ("A1:E30") on worksheet one which contains all the names you're expecting to see returned?

Comment: Yes but also the cell next to it. It's not capturing all the cells next to the names it finds.

Comment: Can you put `Debug.Print aNames(a), rFound.Address` after *bFound = True* then observce in Immediate Window? Just to ensure it is actually found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first `Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(3) = rFound.Value` statement is working correctly if your aim is placing found names every 4th row of "Report" sheet starting from its column E first empty cell after last not empty one

while subsequent `Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(3, 1) ...` statement is always returning the same cell address because it's always finding column F first empty cell after last not empty one and you are not writing any "new" value along that column

furthermore `End` statement is to be avoided since it can bring along unexpected behavior

finally, from a purely code-logic point of view I'd put `Worksheets("Report")` in the With statement instead of `Worksheets("Sheet1")`, so as not to have to access (and repeat) the former multiple times at every loop, while the latter is accessed only one time at a loop, and I'd end up setting this latter to a range variable

for all what above I'd code as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim rFound As Range, rangeToBeSaearchedInRng As Range
    Dim a As Long, aNames As Variant

    aNames = Array("David", "Andrea", "Caroline")

    Set rangeToBeSaearchedInRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E30") '<--| set your range to be searched in and exploit it inside the loop
    With Worksheets("Report") '<--| reference "Report" worksheet
        For a = LBound(aNames) To UBound(aNames)
            Set rFound = rangeToBeSaearchedInRng.Find(What:=aNames(a), MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                bFound = True
                With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(3) '<--| reference referenced worksheet column E first empty cell after last not empty one
                    .Value = rFound.Value '<--| set referenced cell value
                    .Offset(, 1).Value = rFound.Offset(, 1).Value '<--| set the cell value 1 column to the right of referenced cell
                End With
            End If
        Next a
    End With


    If Not bFound Then
        MsgBox "None of the sheets contains the names " & Chr(10) & _
            "'" & Join(aNames, "', '") & "' in cells A1:E30.", vbInformation, "Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate the summary you wrote. It will help me understand. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the `End(xlUp)` function, either logically or systemically (meaning, perhaps Excel can't calculate the changing last row as quickly as it changes). If you find an answer to this question you will still be stuck with the problem that you might be writing the telephone number in a row which is different from where the name is. Therefore why try? It's better to simplify (meaning clarify) the code. For example,

```
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        bFound = True
        With Worksheets("Report")
            R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 3
            .Cells(R, 5).Value = rFound.Value
            .Cells(R, 6).Value = rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End With
    End If
```

Having a more readable code, in passing, also discloses that your setting of bFound is wrong because it isn't set to False anywhere. I suggest the following amendment before and including the first line of your code quoted above.

```
    Set rFound = .Find(What:=aNames(a), MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchFormat:=False)
    bFound = (Not rFound Is Nothing)
    If bFound Then
```